# Image transformation matrix

Tags: image, math, matrix, pixel, transformation

I want to practice pixel manipulation with matrix for extract an image from another.

This is what I have done with css transformation matrix :
https://www.noelshack.com/2017-18-1493893008-capture-2.png

With the Left image 'L' I have place 4 points around the image and in the right image 'R' I find the content of the transformation.

For that i use the property transform of the css but i want to do the manipulation manually.

CSS version :

```
matrix3d(1.5456325781948308,1.6561987730956724,0,0.0012239101773909712,-0.4663849104791486,2.218793881308064,0,0.0009095626603861196,0,0,1,0,12.247969030166722,-17.754955132517754,0,0.9951722722714726)
```

Matrix 'M':

```
[[1.5456325781948308, 1.6561987730956724, 0, 0.0012239101773909712],
[-0.4663849104791486, 2.218793881308064, 0, 0.0009095626603861196],
[0, 0, 1, 0],
[12.247969030166722, -17.754955132517754, 0, 0.9951722722714726]]
```

I want to know for each pixel in the image R what are their pixel related position in the image L.

For example (0,0) in R is (52,203) in R.
For that i do this calculation.

```
M * P = P'
```

P is the pixel position in R image
P' is the pixel position in L image

P matrix is define like that:

```
[[x],
[y],
[0],
[1]]
```

So for the 0,0 position, I do this :

```
[[1.5456325781948308, 1.6561987730956724, 0, 0.0012239101773909712],
[-0.4663849104791486, 2.218793881308064, 0, 0.0009095626603861196],
[0, 0, 1, 0],
[12.247969030166722, -17.754955132517754, 0, 0.9951722722714726]]

X

[[0],
[0],
[0],
[1]]

=

[[0.0012239101773909712],
[0.0009095626603861196],
[0],
[0.9951722722714726]]
```

This is the result, but the 2 first component :
(0.0012239101773909712, 0.0009095626603861196) 
is too smaller than expected. can you help me to find the problem.

scincerly,
MatrixCuriosity.

Comment: Is this matrix for direct transform L->R or for back one R->L? Why matrix is 4x4 instead of 3x3 for 2D transformation? Shift components (12/-17?) look too small.

Comment: Cross reference: see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/339033/35416 for steps to find matrix given four points and their images. The answer and comments include some working JavaScript/CSS demos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are homogeneous coordinates. So given some [x1, y1, z1, 1] as input you obtain some [x2, y2, z2, w2] but the actual position they describe is [x2/w2, y2/w2, z2/w2], i.e. you have to divide by the last coordinate.

But this doesn't lead to the result you expected. Nor does replacing the matrix with its adjunct (or equivalently inverse), nor its transpose. Both of these are conventions that are easy to get wrong, so without spending too much thought about which version you actually have and should have, trying all four alternatives (with and without adjunct, with and without transpose) solves a huge number of trivial problems.

But not yours. So my next best bet would be that the coordinates you expect are measured from some corner of the image, while the CSS property [transform-origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin) is at it's initial value of `50% 50% 0` so the origin of the coordinate system is in fact in the center of the object.

Actually sharing the HTML and CSS for this might have allowed me to verify this assumption. Now you have to check whether this applies to you. I remember that when I last created [a projective image transformation demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dFrHS/1/) to [answer a question about finding the transform](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/339033/35416), I deliberately set `transform-origin: 0 0;` (and the various vendor-prefixed versions of this) to avoid such problems.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot MvG.

I follow your link and I find what I want [https://math.stackexchange.com/a/339033]
Just one thing, I have to invert the C matrix to find the pixel related L<-R

I share my code for give an idea of what you have to do
You can find my implementation in the function **computeMat()**

```
<style>
body {
    touch-action: none;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
#canvas_toeic
{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjs/3.12.2/math.min.js"></script>

</head>



<body>
    <canvas id="canvas_toeic" width="600" height="400">
    </canvas>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var image = new Image(); 
    image.src = 'image.jpg';
    image.onload = function() {

        var c = document.getElementById("canvas_toeic");
        var ratio = image.width / image.height;
        var canvasWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
        var canvasHeight = canvasWidth / ratio;


        if(document.body.clientHeight < canvasHeight)
        {
            canvasHeight = document.body.clientHeight;
            canvasWidth = canvasHeight * ratio;
        }

        var canvasLargeur = canvasWidth;
        var canvasLongueur = canvasHeight;

        if(canvasLargeur < canvasHeight) {
            canvasLargeur = canvasHeight;
            canvasLongueur = canvasWidth;
        }

        var canvasPixelRatio = canvasLargeur / image.width;

        c.setAttribute("width", canvasWidth);
        c.setAttribute("height", canvasHeight);

        var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
        var idPoint = -1;

        var points = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            points[i] = {x:0, y:0};

        var marginImage = Math.round(40 * canvasPixelRatio);

        points[0].x = marginImage;
        points[0].y = marginImage;
        points[1].x = marginImage;
        points[1].y = canvasHeight - marginImage;
        points[2].x = canvasWidth - marginImage;
        points[2].y = canvasHeight - marginImage;
        points[3].x = canvasWidth - marginImage;
        points[3].y = marginImage;

        function draw(points) {
            console.log("draw");

            // Fond
            ctx.fillStyle = "#222";
            ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);

            ctx.drawImage(image, marginImage, marginImage, canvasWidth - marginImage * 2, canvasHeight - marginImage * 2); // this fait référence à l'objet courant (=image)

            if(idPoint == -1)
                ctx.lineWidth = 3 * canvasPixelRatio;
            else
                ctx.lineWidth = 5 * canvasPixelRatio;

            ctx.beginPath();      // Début du chemin
            ctx.lineJoin = "round";
            ctx.lineCap = "round";
            ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(64, 128, 255, 0.5)";
            ctx.moveTo(points[0].x, points[0].y);    // Le tracé part du point 50,50
            for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                ctx.lineTo(points[i].x, points[i].y);  // Un segment est ajouté vers 200,200
            ctx.closePath();      // Fermeture du chemin (facultative)
            ctx.stroke();


            for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                var radius = 30 * canvasPixelRatio;

                if(idPoint == i)
                    radius = 60 * canvasPixelRatio;

                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.arc(points[i].x, points[i].y, radius, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
                ctx.strokeStyle = "#FF8800";
                ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 128, 0, 0.5)";
                ctx.fill();
                ctx.stroke();
            }

            if(idPoint != -1)
            {
                var zoomWidth = canvasWidth / 3;
                var zoomHeight = canvasHeight / 3;
                var zoomMargin = 5;
                var zoomAroundWidth = 50; 
                var zoomAroundHeight = zoomAroundWidth / ratio;

                var positionMouse = points[idPoint];
                var imagePositionX = (positionMouse.x - marginImage) / (canvasWidth - marginImage * 2) * image.width;
                var imagePositionY = (positionMouse.y - marginImage) / (canvasHeight - marginImage * 2) * image.height;

                var zoomX = 0;
                var zoomY = 0;

                if(imagePositionX < image.width / 2)
                    zoomX = canvasWidth - zoomWidth;
                if(imagePositionY < image.height / 2)
                    zoomY = canvasHeight - zoomHeight;

                ctx.fillStyle = "#F08";
                ctx.fillRect(zoomX, zoomY, zoomWidth, zoomHeight);
                ctx.drawImage(image, imagePositionX - zoomAroundWidth, imagePositionY - zoomAroundHeight, zoomAroundWidth * 2, zoomAroundHeight * 2, zoomX + zoomMargin, zoomY + zoomMargin, zoomWidth - zoomMargin * 2, zoomHeight - zoomMargin * 2);

                ctx.lineWidth = 3 * canvasPixelRatio;

                ctx.beginPath();      
                ctx.lineJoin = "round";
                ctx.lineCap = "round";
                ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)";
                ctx.moveTo(zoomX, zoomY + zoomHeight / 2);    
                ctx.lineTo(zoomX + zoomWidth, zoomY + zoomHeight / 2);
                ctx.moveTo(zoomX + zoomWidth / 2, zoomY);    
                ctx.lineTo(zoomX + zoomWidth / 2, zoomY + zoomHeight);
                ctx.closePath(); 
                ctx.stroke();
            }
        }

        function nearPoint(points, x, y)
        {
            var radiusDetection = 60 * canvasPixelRatio;
            var distances = [];

            for(i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                var mx = x - points[i].x;
                var my = y - points[i].y;
                distances[i] = Math.sqrt(mx * mx + my * my);
            }

            minI = 0;
            minD = distances[0];

            for(i = 1; i < 4; i++)
            {
                if(minD > distances[i])
                {
                    minD = distances[i];
                    minI = i;
                }
            }

            if(minD <= radiusDetection)
                return minI;

            return -1;
        }

        function getTouchPosition(e)
        {
            var target = null;
            var mouse = null;

            if(e.changedTouches != undefined)
            {
                var touches = e.changedTouches;
                mouse = touches[0];
                target = touches[0].target;
            }
            else if(e.originalTarget != undefined)
            {
                mouse = e;
                target = e.originalTarget;
            }

            var coordX = 0;
            var coordY = 0;

            if(mouse.layerX != undefined)
            {
                coordX = mouse.layerX;
                coordY = mouse.layerY;
            }
            else
            {
                coordX = mouse.pageX;
                coordY = mouse.pageY;
            }

            var x = coordX - target.offsetLeft;
            var y = coordY - target.offsetTop;

            if(x < 0) x = 0;
            if(y < 0) y = 0;
            if(x >= canvasWidth) x = canvasWidth - 1;
            if(y >= canvasHeight) y = canvasHeight - 1;

            return {'x':x, 'y':y};
        }

        function mouseDown(e)
        {
            var position = getTouchPosition(e);

            idPoint = nearPoint(points, position.x, position.y);

            if(idPoint == -1)
            {
                if(position.x < marginImage * 3 && position.y < marginImage * 3)
                {
                    computeMat();
                }   
            }
        }

        function mouseUp(e)
        {
            if(idPoint != -1)
            {
                idPoint = -1;
                draw(points);
            }
        }

        function mouseMove(e)
        {
            if(idPoint != -1)
            {
                var position = getTouchPosition(e);
                points[idPoint].x = position.x;
                points[idPoint].y = position.y;
                draw(points);
            }
        }

        function cancelDefault(e)
        {
            e.preventDefault();
        }

        function matStep12(pts)
        {
            var matP = [
                [pts[0].x, pts[1].x, pts[2].x],
                [pts[0].y, pts[1].y, pts[2].y],
                [1, 1, 1]
                ];

            var vecP = [[pts[3].x], [pts[3].y], [1]];

            var matPi = math.inv(matP);
            var vecPi = math.multiply(matPi, vecP);

            var result = [
                    [pts[0].x * vecPi[0][0], pts[1].x * vecPi[1][0], pts[2].x * vecPi[2][0]],
                    [pts[0].y * vecPi[0][0], pts[1].y * vecPi[1][0], pts[2].y * vecPi[2][0]],
                    [vecPi[0][0], vecPi[1][0], vecPi[2][0]]
                ];

            return result;
        }

        function distance(a, b)
        {
            var mx = b.x - a.x;
            var my = b.y - a.y;

            return Math.sqrt(mx * mx + my * my);
        }

        function computeMat()
        {
            var pts = getPointRelativePosition();

            var widthT = distance(pts[0], pts[3]);
            var widthB = distance(pts[1], pts[2]);
            var heightL = distance(pts[0], pts[1]);
            var heightR = distance(pts[2], pts[3]);

            var maxWidth = (widthT > widthB) ? widthT : widthB;
            var maxHeight = (heightL > heightR) ? heightL : heightR;
            var imgWidth = Math.round(maxWidth);
            var imgHeight = Math.round(maxHeight);


            var matA = matStep12(pts);
            var matB = matStep12([{x:0,y:0}, {x:0,y:maxHeight}, {x:maxWidth,y:maxHeight}, {x:maxWidth,y:0}]);
            var matC = math.multiply(matB, math.inv(matA));
            var matCi = math.inv(matC);

            console.log('width:' + imgWidth + ', height:' + imgHeight);
            printMat(matC);


            // construct image with transformation matrice

            imageData = ctx.createImageData(imgWidth, imgHeight);

            var tempCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            var tempCtx = tempCanvas.getContext('2d');
            tempCanvas.width = image.width;
            tempCanvas.height = image.height;
            tempCtx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);
            var imageDataSrc = tempCtx.getImageData(0, 0, image.width, image.height);

            var mz = [matCi[0][2], matCi[1][2], matCi[2][2]];

            for(var y = 0; y < imgHeight; y++)
            {
                var my = [matCi[0][1] * y, matCi[1][1] * y, matCi[2][1] * y];

                var offsetY = y * imgWidth;
                for(var x = 0; x < imgWidth; x++)
                {
                    var mx = [matCi[0][0] * x, matCi[1][0] * x, matCi[2][0] * x];

                    var cx = mx[0] + my[0] + mz[0];
                    var cy = mx[1] + my[1] + mz[1];
                    var cz = mx[2] + my[2] + mz[2];

                    var px = Math.round(cx / cz);
                    var py = Math.round(cy / cz);

                    if(px < 0.0 || py < 0.0 || px >= image.width || py >= image.height)
                    {
                        imageData.data[pixelIndex] = 0;
                        imageData.data[pixelIndex + 1] = 255;
                        imageData.data[pixelIndex + 2] = 0;
                        imageData.data[pixelIndex + 3] = 255;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var pixelIndex = (offsetY + x) * 4;
                        var pixelIndexSrc = (py * image.width + px) * 4;

                        imageData.data[pixelIndex] = imageDataSrc.data[pixelIndexSrc];
                        imageData.data[pixelIndex + 1] = imageDataSrc.data[pixelIndexSrc + 1];
                        imageData.data[pixelIndex + 2] = imageDataSrc.data[pixelIndexSrc + 2];
                        imageData.data[pixelIndex + 3] = 255;
                    }
                }
            }



            // here to do, image analysis

        }

        function getPointRelativePosition()
        {
            var pointOrigin = [];

            for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                pointOrigin[i] = {x:(points[i].x - marginImage) * image.width / (canvasWidth - marginImage * 2), y:(points[i].y - marginImage) * image.height / (canvasHeight - marginImage * 2)};
            }

            return pointOrigin;
        }

        function getPointPosition()
        {
            var pointOrigin = [];

            for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                pointOrigin[i] = {x:(points[i].x - marginImage) / (canvasWidth - marginImage * 2), y:(points[i].y - marginImage) / (canvasHeight - marginImage * 2)};
            }

            return pointOrigin;
        }

        function printPoint(pts)
        {
            var result = '';


            for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                result += "{x:" + pts[i].x + ", y:" + pts[i].y + "},\n";
            }

            console.log(result);
        }

        function printMat(mat)
        {
            var result = '';

            for(var i = 0; i < mat.length; i++)
            {
                result += "[";

                for(var j = 0; j < mat[i].length; j++)
                {
                    result += mat[i][j] + ", ";
                }

                result += "],\n";
            }

            console.log(result);
        }

        function canvasResize()
        {
            if(canvasWidth != document.body.clientWidth && canvasHeight != document.body.clientHeight)
            {
                var transformPoint = getPointPosition();

                ratio = image.width / image.height;
                canvasWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
                canvasHeight = canvasWidth / ratio;


                if(document.body.clientHeight < canvasHeight)
                {
                    canvasHeight = document.body.clientHeight;
                    canvasWidth = canvasHeight * ratio;
                }

                canvasLargeur = canvasWidth;
                canvasLongueur = canvasHeight;

                if(canvasLargeur < canvasHeight) {
                    canvasLargeur = canvasHeight;
                    canvasLongueur = canvasWidth;
                }

                canvasPixelRatio = canvasLargeur / image.width;

                c.setAttribute("width", canvasWidth);
                c.setAttribute("height", canvasHeight);

                marginImage = Math.round(40 * canvasPixelRatio);

                for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                {
                    points[i].x = transformPoint[i].x * (canvasWidth - marginImage * 2) + marginImage;
                    points[i].y = transformPoint[i].y * (canvasHeight - marginImage * 2) + marginImage;
                }

                draw(points);
            }
        }

        c.addEventListener("mousedown", mouseDown, false);
        c.addEventListener("mouseup", mouseUp, false);
        c.addEventListener("mousemove", mouseMove, false);

        c.addEventListener("touchstart", mouseDown, false);
        c.addEventListener("touchend", mouseUp, false);
        c.addEventListener("touchmove", mouseMove, false);

        document.addEventListener("touchstart", cancelDefault, true);
        document.addEventListener("touchend", cancelDefault, true);
        document.addEventListener("touchmove", cancelDefault, true);

        setInterval(canvasResize, 30);

        draw(points);

    };



</script>
```